# How to re-size/crop images to the same size?

Tags: html, css

I have two `<img>` elements side-by-side (see code below, and [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/cagross/pen/JVbqvd)).  I would like to ensure they are re-sized and/or cropped to the exact same dimensions--500 x 300--using HTML/CSS alone (i.e. no pre-processing of the images using Photoshop).  Additionally, as screen width decreases, I'd like these dimensions to scale down proportionately with screen width.  How can I do that, without replacing the `<img>` elements with CSS `background-image`?

I understand some cropping may occur--that is acceptable.

---

**HTML**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
  width: 60%;
}

.d_block {
  display: block;
}

img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: auto;
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="d_block">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.everasia.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2835-m2-Excellent-Sea-View-Land-For-Sale-In-Plai-Laem-06-1170x738-610x385.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.everasia.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/1300-m2-Of-Premium-Sea-View-Land-For-Sale-In-Plai-Laem-06-610x458.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [object fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) with a polyfill for ie - then it works like background-size

Comment: Also use the [padding top trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) to keep your aspect ratio

Comment: The duplicates are a couple of examples of how to use these things together

Comment: use 'vh' rather than 'px' to assign height to image, that way it'll readjust as the window size changes